# copy section of text in file python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to extract values from the text file below:

```
fdsjhgjhg
fdshkjhk
Start
Good Morning
Hello World
End
dashjkhjk
dsfjkhk
```

The values I need to extract are from Start to End.

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == "Start":
            copy = True
        elif line.strip() == "End":
            copy = False
        elif copy:
            outfile.write(line)
```

The code above I am using is from this question:
[Extract Values between two strings in a text file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865058/extract-values-between-two-strings-in-a-text-file-using-python#)

This code will not include the strings "Start" and "End" just what is inside them. How would you include the perimeter strings?

Comment: I would use multiline RegExp for that - the code will also look much easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@en_Knight has it almost right.  Here's a fix to meet the OP's request that the delimiters ARE included in the output:

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == "Start":
            copy = True
        if copy:
            outfile.write(line)
        # move this AFTER the "if copy"
        if line.strip() == "End":
            copy = False
```

OR simply include the write() in the case it applies to:

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == "Start":
            outfile.write(line) # add this
            copy = True
        elif line.strip() == "End":
            outfile.write(line) # add this
            copy = False
        elif copy:
            outfile.write(line)
```

**Update**: to answer the question in the comment "only use the 1st occurance of 'End' after 'Start'", change the last `elif line.strip() == "End"` to:

```
        elif line.strip() == "End" and copy:
            outfile.write(line) # add this
            copy = False
```

This works if there is only ONE "Start" but multiple "End" lines... which sounds odd, but that is what the questioner asked.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Is it possible to be selective and end the copy only use the 1st occurance of 'End' after 'Start'. My file contains a number of strings 'End'?

Comment: @Dan H what if there is a `Start` after `End` how to prevent to copy this `Strat`? and stop copying immediately

Comment: @Catalina : options: 1) call exit() after you see "End".  2) count the number of starts you see; only set copy to "True" if this is the first one.

Answer (score 1):

The "`elif`" [means](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) "do this only if the other cases fail". It's syntactically equivalent to "`else if`", [if you're coming from a differnet C-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395160/what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-else-if) language. Without it, the fall through should take care of including "Start" and "End"

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == "Start":
            copy = True
        if copy: # flipped to include end, as Dan H pointed out
            outfile.write(line)
        if line.strip() == "End":
            copy = False
```

Answer (score 1):

RegExp approach:

```
import re

with open('input.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()

match = re.search(r'\n(Start\n.*?\nEnd)\n', data, re.M | re.S)
if match:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(match.group(1))
```

Comment: This is probably the more robust solution, but for someone who was unclear on elif v if, maybe you could include some textual description?

Comment: This is better: `(^Start[\s\S]+^End)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gT0eR6/1) (Or `(^Start[\s\S]+?^End)` if there is more than 1 `End`...)